# How can I make tensorflow variables 'local'?

Tags: python, tensorflow

It seems the tensorflow variables made by either `tf.get_variable()` or `tf.Variable()` are global variables. What happened to me is like the below: Suppose I make the following two files:

1. main.py

   ```
   from prac_var import defineVar
   for i in range(1000):
       defineVar()
   ```
2. prac_var.py

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf
   def defineVar():
       with tf.variable_scope('weight'):    
           W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]),name='W')
           print('\n',tf.trainable_variables())
   ```

Now if I run main.py, it produces

```
[<tf.Variable 'weight/W:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>]

[<tf.Variable 'weight/W:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'weight_1/W:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>]

[<tf.Variable 'weight/W:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'weight_1/W:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'weight_2/W:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>]
...
```

whereas what I really want is

```
[<tf.Variable 'weight/W:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>]
[<tf.Variable 'weight/W:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>]
[<tf.Variable 'weight/W:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>]
...
```

**How can I possibly fix this problem in a nontrivial way?**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I was wondering if you understand that Tensorflow first constructs a computation graph, and then does all the computations with the graph you defined. All variables can be reached from everywhere by using `tf.get_variable()` if you know the name of the variable...

If you get weights at two different places both times trying to get the variable `W` you "reuse" these weights. This is why variable scopes are introduced: 
 https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope#variable_scope_example

If you want to have two different weights, you can say:

```
with tf.variable_scope('mnistweights'):
  Wmnist = tf.get_variable('W',...)
with tf.variable_scope('exampleweights'):
  Wtest = tf.get_variable('W',...)
```

Now you have the variables with the names mnistweights/W and exampleweights/W.

Hope you understand it better!

Comment: I think I haven't conveyed my point clearly to you. Could you once more have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

I've accidently found a solution to my problem. It is simply to add a line `tf.reset_default_graph()`.

1. main.py

   ```
   from prac_var import defineVar
   for i in range(1000):
       defineVar()
   ```
2. prac_var.py

   ```
   import tensorflow as tf
   def defineVar():
       tf.reset_default_graph()
       with tf.variable_scope('weight'):    
           W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]),name='W')
           print('\n',tf.trainable_variables())
   ```

Comment: What is it that you want exactly? Now you remove the weights and add them again 1000 times...